# Import Email Addresses and Update the User's manager

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file that contains 2 columns. The first is the AD user's email and the second is that AD User's Manager's email.
I need a script that will read the csv file and update the User's Manager in AD based on the Manager's email in the csv.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you haven't done yet you may read the help topic about [Ask] to set your expectations on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the first thing you want to do is list the steps you want to take.

1. Read and use the CSV
2. Get the AD User
3. Get the Manager
4. Set the Manager
5. Combine the scripts

> 1. Google for 'powershell csv'. You will find the Import-CSV command. Then you will have to test out what you can do with the CSV.
> 2. Google for 'Get AD User'. You will find the Get-ADUser command.
> 3. The manager must also be present in AD and will use the same command as in step 2.
> 4. Google for 'set manager AD'. You will find that it is possible with the Set-ADUser command.
> 5. Now you will have to combine and use some logic to put the pieces together

There are a lot of different ways to achieve it, but here is a simple example:

```
$csvFile = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\ad_managers.csv" -Delimiter ";" # Check what delimiter you use comma or semicolon

foreach($user in $csvFile){
    $usersEmail = $user.userEmail # Note that userEmail is the column header name
    $managersEmail = $user.managerEmail # Note that managerEmail is the column header name
    if($usersEmail -and $managersEmail){
        $adUser = $false
        $adManager = $false
        try{
            $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {Emailaddress -eq $usersEmail} -Properties manager
            $adManager = Get-ADUser -Filter {Emailaddress -eq $managersEmail}
        }catch{
            Write-Host "Error while searching for user, error: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
            break
        }
        if($adUser -and $adManager){
            try{
                Write-Host "Setting manager: $($adManager.Name) for user: $($adManager.Name)"
                Set-ADUser -Identity $adUser.objectGUID.Guid -Manager $adManager.objectGuid.Guid -Confirm:$false -WhatIf # What if will show what it would do without actually doing it
            }catch{
                Write-Host "Error while setting manager: $($adManager.Name) for user: $($adManager.Name), error: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
                break    
            }
        }else{
            Write-Host "Not all mandatory values found. User: $usersEmail. Manager: $managersEmail." -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to try and understand each part and Google for additional logic and explanation!

Comment: Thanks Bernard, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Hi Bernard, A couple of corrections of $adUser to $adManager, but then worked like a charm. Thanks you so much for this. I am still learning Powershell and help like this goes a long way.

Comment: You're welcome! As you can see on the downvotes, the question should be specific and must contain the code you have tried so far. Nevertheless hope this kickstarts your PowerShell learning and next time we'll play by the rules again ;)

Comment: Well, you totally got what I was asking! Nailed it! Sorry you couldn't get a score